# Is the sentence "In case of your going fast, you will catch the bus," correct?

Tags: grammar

This question is related to prepositional phrase. I suggested that "In case of going fast, you will catch the bus."

Comment: If you run fast enough you can catch the bus.

Comment: I would say 'In case you go fast...'

Comment: We normally use 'in case of' to refer to possible undesirable events ('in case of fire, sound the alarm' - 'take an umbrella in case it rains') rather than something you do to obtain a desired outcome (catching a bus).

Comment: Are you trying to say *if you need to get there quickly, you should catch the bus* or (as with an answer already provided) *if you hurry, you can catch the bus*?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

> "If you go now, you will catch the bus."
>
> "If you act quickly, you might still be able to catch the bus."
>
> "If you run quickly, you will catch the bus."

These should be more effective wordings for your goal.

Comment: Lol someone downvoted this? Please, pray tell, what is wrong about this?

Answer (score 0):

The usage is awkward. As noted by Kate, *in case of* tends to connote undesirable events.

Consider the following alternatives:

> "If you go fast, you will catch the bus."
>
> "If you hurry, you can catch the bus."
>
> "If you hurry, you can still catch the bus."